# How can I enlarge my webcam on Skype?

Tags: skype

I use Skype software installed on Windows laptop. Currently when I video-chat with someone, my webcam (red arrow) is teeny. How can I enlarge it? Nothing happened after I double clicked  the other person's teeny screen.

[image]

I prefer something like a split screen.

[image]

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't, at least not natively with Skype. Assuming it's still even possible, you'd likely need third-party software for that.

Comment: Did you tried to (double)click over it? You should be able to switch the two outputs...

Comment: If I remember well under windows, if you click on your video it appears a small handle in the top left (or bottom right) corner. Then you can resize it [dragging off (on)](https://www.wikihow.com/Resize-a-Skype-Video-Chat-on-PC-or-Mac)... You should be able to do it in a full view mode too. In [group-calls](https://blogs.skype.com/tips/2014/09/18/how-to-adjust-video-size-on-skype-group-calls/) you can have something as you shown with the _normal view_ setting.

Comment: try double click on it.

Comment: @Hastur Double click where? The other person's teeny screen? That did nothing.

Comment: @Coder123 Double click where? The other person's teeny screen? That did nothing.

Comment: @Vast Follow the links in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* I may have found a solution...*hopefully*.

1. After some cursory searching I found [this article](https://blogs.skype.com/tips/2014/09/18/how-to-adjust-video-size-on-skype-group-calls/)
2. It's from 2014 though, so I began to delve a bit deeper by checking out The Skype Community. There I did a bunch of filtering and searching and found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-calling-problems-on-macos-yosemite/367eb267-1154-4ca6-852c-91609d2052d5?auth=1) (Created *today*):

   > We have just released (February 11, 2020) a new version of Skype for
   >   Mac which will fix the calling problems you might have seen on macOS
   >   10.10 (Yosemite).
   >        You can download and install it from [here](https://go.skype.com/mac.download).

   I'm not sure if you have Yosemite, but I figured you might want to check it out and/or reinstall just in case.
3. I'd also recommend looking at this [filtered search for video layout](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=video%20layout%20mac&tab=&status=all&advFil=&IsSuggestedTerm=false&isFilterExpanded=undefined&CurrentScope.ForumName=skype&CurrentScope.Filter=&ContentTypeScope=&page=1&sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc) to find the release notes of the Skype version you have on Mac and whether you should update to get that layout feature.

Hopefully one of those solutions help!